# Get device token (iphone) and implement push notifications, using cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building my first mobile app using Apache Cordova (Initially for IOS, and may extend to Android later), what is going well so far... Now I need to implement push notifications. As I think its going to be, I will:

- Get the device token
- Send the token to my server using my REST API
- From my server I will send eventual notifications using the APNS.

The main intention of the push notifications is to make the user open the app, to provide some data updates.

If my thinking is right, I need first to get the device token... for what I would like to ask.. What plugin can i use to:

- Get the device token
- Get permissions or register (if I need), for me to send the notifications from my server and relate them to the app... so the user click the notification and open the app.

Any guidance (or correction) on how to approach this is welcomed, as well as any recommendations for plugins to do this.

Comment: just use the firebase plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) is all you need for this.

**A word of warning**: avoid sending notifications with the deprecated GCM or APNS, instead you can use this plugin to receive FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) notifications in both Android and iOS, using a single notifications API. The downside of Firebase? You never know when Google will start **charging you money** for its use.

Also, be **very careful** what version of the plugin you get, there is a compatibility table for this. **You can't expect to simply use the latest version** with any Cordova, cordova-android or cordova-ios platforms, ignoring this will certainly lead to notifications not working.